# Pandas' diff but user defined function

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas' `pandas.DataFrame.diff` almost does what I'm attempting to do.

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
...                    'b': [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
...                    'c': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]})
>>> df
   a  b   c
0  1  1   1
1  2  1   4
2  3  2   9
3  4  3  16
4  5  5  25
5  6  8  36
```

`df.diff(axis=0)` and `df.diff(axis=1)` respectively produces

```
>>> df.diff()
     a    b     c
0  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  1.0  0.0   3.0
2  1.0  1.0   5.0
3  1.0  1.0   7.0
4  1.0  2.0   9.0
5  1.0  3.0  11.0

>>> df.diff(axis=1)
    a    b     c
0 NaN  0.0   0.0
1 NaN -1.0   3.0
2 NaN -1.0   7.0
3 NaN -1.0  13.0
4 NaN  0.0  20.0
5 NaN  2.0  28.0
```

What `df.diff` is doing is essentially applying this function

```
def diff_func(columns):
    return columns[1:] - columns[0:-1]
```

I want to define my own function, which replace the `diff_func`.
What I want to is "apply" my own function (possibly nonlinear) to the consecutive (`periods=1`) columns/rows. For example, `func(x,y) = sin(x)*cos(y)` where `x,y` are consecutive columns or rows of `periods=n`

Comment: This is too vague. An actual solution to your problem would require some substantial explanation from your side. How about it?

Comment: @coldspeed Is this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that works for me using pandas DataFrame built-in method 'apply'.

I wrapped the custom diff function, `product`, which takes two arguments and returns one value, in `diff_custom` which takes a vector argument and returns an equal length vector, appropriately NaN-padded. We execute `diff_custom` using the the pandas DataFrame's built-in `apply` method:

```
import pandas
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame([[4, 9],[5,10],[22,44]], columns=['A', 'B'])

# Function that acts on neighboring row or column values, val1 and val2
def product(val1,val2):
    return(val1*val2)

# Function that acts on DataFrame row or column, x
def diff_custom(x):
    vals = [product(x[n],x[n+1]) for n in range(x.shape[0]-1)]
    ret = list([numpy.nan]) # pad return vector however you need to
    ret = ret + vals
    return(ret)

# Use DataFrame built-in 'apply' method
df.apply(diff_custom,axis=1)
    A      B
0 NaN   36.0
1 NaN   50.0
2 NaN  968.0

df.apply(diff_custom,axis=0)
       A      B
0    NaN    NaN
1   20.0   90.0
2  110.0  440.0
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did, so this answer will be much more useful for future users? :)

Comment: sure thing! added some more explanation. hope it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

The you should consider `shift`

```
df-df.shift(1)
     a    b     c
0  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  1.0  0.0   3.0
2  1.0  1.0   5.0
3  1.0  1.0   7.0
4  1.0  2.0   9.0
5  1.0  3.0  11.0
```

Comment: Not really what I’m search for as a response